# Determine a Function by a List of its Nth Derivative for each N.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Is there any easy way to take a list of the derivative of a function , 2nd derivative, etc, and determine the original function?  I am wondering because I am trying to turn the Taylor Series 
$$1+(x^4)/4! + (x^8)/8! + (x^{12})/12! + (x^{16})/16! \ldots$$
into the original function.  How might I do this?

Comment: Could you do it for $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots$?

Comment: $$\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dots\\\frac1{1-x^4}=1+x^4+x^8+\dots$$

Comment: I think you mean the derivatives of the function *evaluated at 0*. It is in principle impossible to do this for functions which are infinitely differentiable but not real analytic. The coefficients of a power series can be fairly arbitrary and seldom correspond to elementary functions. Of course, in special cases you can do this, easily so at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer after OP has modified his question:

Recall that the exponential function can be written as

$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

This looks a bit like your function, but it has some additional terms. Let's see if we can get rid of them.

By adding $e^{-x}$ and dividing by two we can eliminate all odd exponents: 
$$\frac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x}) = \frac{1}{2} \left (\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}\right ) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\tag{1}$$

This is the power series of $\cosh(x)$, by the way.

The exponents in our series are now $0, 2, 4, 6, 8, \ldots$. In order to arrive at your series, we therefore have to eliminate every other term of $(1)$.

This can be achieved by adding $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}$ to to $(1)$ and dividing by two:
$$\frac{1}{2} \left (\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!} \right )  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4k}}{(4k)!}$$

As stated before, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$ is $\cosh(x)$. Now recall that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}$ is simply $\cos(x)$.

Therefore the function you're looking for is $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} (\cosh(x) + \cos(x))$.

Comment: sorry.  I forgot to put in the divided by 4!, 8!, 12!, part.  Stupid me!

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect your edit.

Answer (score 0):

$1+x^4 + x^8 + x^{12} + x^{16} \ldots$

is a geometric series with ratio $x^4$ and the sum is

$\dfrac{1}{1-x^4},\;x^4<1\to |x|<1$